# javascript/php - record click destination before redirect

Tags: php, javascript, hyperlink, onclick, record

Say I have the link:

```
    <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
```

Is there any way I can record the click (with php/sql)? For example an onclick event to load ajax? Would the ajax run before the page redirects? I want to avoid:

```
    <a href="record_click.php?url=http://www.google.com">google</a>
```

Comment: I would recommend the approach you want to avoid. You can update external links on the page via JS so you don't have to write this everywhere. Seems simpler to me that trying to do something via AJAX, although that would certainly work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your link to:

```
<a href="test.php" onclick="javascript: recordClick(this); return false;">TEST</a>
```

And then use the function:

```
function recordClick(t) {
    //Insert AJAX here. t contains the URL
    document.location = t;
}
```

You could then wait for the AJAX request to complete before using the document.location part. However I would suggest simply using a separate file to log clicks like you have already suggested because it is an immediate action that doesn't require JS to be on, and that provides immediate feedback.